# How to add a DOM Element in a overflow:hidden area?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am creating a control that displays table-data per year. The DOM Elements of type `table` are added to a `div` that has `overflow` set to `hidden`. The tables have `position` set to `relative`. The `height` of the `div` is set fixed to the height of one table so that only one table is visible at a time.

I have a paging mechanism that pages forward and backward and animates the transition by changing the `top` property of the tables so that it looks like the table-data is sliding up and downwards. Like a classic calendar.

The problem I am facing is this: when adding a new Element, I would like to add it to the hidden part of the div-content on top of the existing table, in order to animate it into view after adding it to the DOM Tree. Is this possible without "hacks"?

I have tried to change the `top` property of the tables before adding them to the `div` but that doesn't put them into the `overflow:hidden` part of the `div`.

How can I achieve that?

This is what I have so far in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34v6R/2/

**Update**

I have also tried to use hide() and slideDown() but the animation of slideDown seems to be not very fluent (at least in jsfiddle)

```
$(markup).hide().prependTo('.overviewContainer').slideDown();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34v6R/6

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of what you've got?

Comment: so you're adding new rows? i might be able to help if you post a code snippet

Comment: @MartinOngtangco no I'm adding complete tables, I'm preparing a jsfiddle right now.

Comment: @scragar I have added the link to the jsfiddle

Comment: Looking at the fiddle you've got some funny behaviours being show, especially if you change the dropdown to 2013, 2012, 2014 in that order. I'm at work at the moment, but if no-one has solved your problem I'll have a stab when I get a chance.

Comment: @scragar yes the Code is far from ready. Currently you cannot skip years because that breaks the behavior. But the sequence you mentioned should Show each table without animation and when selecting 2014 again it should Animate all the Way down. What I am missing is the animation when adding new tables in this case when selecting 2013 and then 2012. Note also that in those cases the new tables should be "prepended" above the existing 2014 table which in fact seems also to be the difficult Part.

Answer (score 1):

How is the size of your  specified ? If you are not using "height:500px" or some such, then the div simply is extended when you add new elements to it.

Comment: Actually, given the partial question we had, adding "height:500px" was my answer to the question. It might not be applicable depending on his CSS, of course, but we haven't seen that.

Comment: I have added that information to the question to clarify that the height of the container div has already been set.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**:

In a comment, you've said

> The problem I am facing is that I want to prepend the new table...

...and I confirmed with you that you want the new table to slide in from the top.

Most of the discussion in the original answer below covers what we need to do and how we do it, here's an example of doing it whether you're having the table come in from the top or come in from the bottom: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zumara/3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    #parent {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }
    #parent table {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Back" data-direction="-1">
  <input type="button" value="Forward" data-direction="1">
  <div id="parent">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zero</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var tables, current, busy;

    tables = prepTables();
    current = 0;
    buttonSetup();
    busy = false;
    enableForIndex(current);

    function prepTables() {
      var zero, one, two;

      // Copy the zero table to create "one" and "two", with varying
      // numbers of rows
      zero = $("#parent table");
      one = zero.clone();
      two = zero.clone();
      one.find("td").html("One");
      one.find("tr").slice(1, 5).clone().appendTo(one.find("tbody"));
      two.find("td").html("Two");
      one.find("tr").slice(1, 3).remove();
      return [zero, one, two];
    }

    function buttonSetup() {
      $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
        var direction = +this.getAttribute("data-direction"),
            index;

        if (!busy) {
          index = current + direction;
          if (index >= 0 && index < tables.length) {
            $("input[type=button").prop("disabled", true);
            busy = true;
            swapTables(index, function() {
              busy = false;
              current = index;
              enableForIndex(current);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function enableForIndex(index) {
      $("input[data-direction=-1]").prop("disabled", index === 0);
      $("input[data-direction=1]").prop("disabled", index === tables.length - 1);
    }

    function swapTables(index, callback) {
      var parent, height,
          table, tableHeight,
          newTable, newTableHeight,
          bothTables,
          target,
          tableTop,
          newHeight;

      // Get the parent
      parent = $("#parent");

      // Get its height
      height = parent.height();
      parent.css({
        height: height,
        maxHeight: height,
        minHeight: height
      });

      // Get the current table and the desired table
      table = tables[current];
      newTable = tables[index];
      bothTables = table.add(newTable);

      // Remember the current table's top
      tableTop = table.position().top;

      // Insert the new table, change tops if necessary,
      // figure out where our animation should stop
      tableHeight = table.height();
      if (index < current) {
        newTable.insertBefore(table);
        newTableHeight = newTable.height();
        table.css("top", "-=" + newTableHeight);
        newTable.css("top", tableTop - newTableHeight);
        target = tableTop;
      } else {
        newTable.insertAfter(table);
        newTableHeight = newTable.height();
        target = tableTop - newTable.position().top;
      }

      // If the new table is a different size, animate that
      // at the same time, but make sure we finish first
      if (newTableHeight != tableHeight) {
        height += newTableHeight - tableHeight;
        parent.animate({
          height: height,
          maxHeight: height,
          minHeight: height
        }, 1000); // 200ms shorter than the below
      }

      // Animate both tables, get a single callback when the animation is complete
      // (using the `animate` callback, we'd get two -- one for each table -- so
      // we use the promise instead)
      bothTables.animate({
        top: target
      }, 1200).promise().then(function() {
        var newHeight;

        // Complete, detach the old one and put the new one in its normal position
        table.detach().css("top", "");
        newTable.css("top", tableTop);

        // Let the parent assume its natural height again; in
        // theory, this should be the new height we set for it
        // earlier if that needed to change
        parent.css({
          height: "",
          maxHeight: "",
          minHeight: ""
        });

        // Done
        callback();
      });
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Original Answer**:

The key here is that the parent `div` has to have a specific height set on it (either a fixed number, or because it's some percentage of the height of its container, etc.). Otherwise, adding the second table will extend the `div` vertically, and so the second table won't be hidden.

If you want the `div` to have its "natural" height, then you'll just need to fix the height during the operation, then you can release it again. I'll give that variant below.

Once you've done that, it's fairly straightforward — comments in the code below explain.

Here's the version assuming the `div` already has a fixed height: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zumara/1)

```
var height, table, newTable, target;

// Get the height of the parent div
height = $("#parent").height();

// Get the table
table = $("#parent table");

// Add the new table (in my case I'll just clone that one)
newTable = table.clone();
newTable.find("td").text("Two");
newTable.appendTo("#parent");

// Figure out where we want to stop the animation of `top`
target = table.position().top - newTable.position().top;

// Animate both tables, get a single callback when the animation is complete
// (using the `animate` callback, we'd get two -- one for each table -- so
// we use the promise instead)
newTable.add(table).animate({
  top: target
}, 1200).promise().then(function() {
  // Complete, remove the old one and put the new one in its normal position
  table.remove();
  newTable.css("top", 0);
});
```

Or if we need to fix the height only during the animation, we measure it when we start, then fix it, do the animation, then un-fix it (possibly animating to a new height): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zumara/2)

```
var parent, height, table, newTable, target;

// Get the parent
parent = $("#parent");

// Get its height
height = parent.height();
parent.css({
  height: height,
  maxHeight: height,
  minHeight: height
});

// Get the table
table = parent.find("table");

// Add the new table (in my case I'll just clone that one, and add
// more rows)
newTable = table.clone();
newTable.find("td").text("Two");
newTable.find("tr").slice(1, 5).clone().appendTo(newTable.find("tbody"));
newTable.appendTo(parent);

// Figure out where we want to stop the animation of `top`
target = table.position().top - newTable.position().top;

// Animate both tables, get a single callback when the animation is complete
// (using the `animate` callback, we'd get two -- one for each table -- so
// we use the promise instead)
newTable.add(table).animate({
  top: target
}, 1200).promise().then(function() {
  var newHeight;

  // Complete, remove the old one and put the new one in its normal position
  table.remove();
  newTable.css("top", 0);

  // Let the parent assume its natural height again; if the new table is a
  // different size, just clearing the heights we set would be abrupt, so
  // we animate again
  parent.css({
    height: "",
    maxHeight: "",
    minHeight: ""
  });
  newHeight = parent.height();
  if (newHeight !== height) {
    parent.css({
      height: height,
      maxHeight: height,
      minHeight: height
    }).animate({
      height: newHeight,
      maxHeight: newHeight,
      minHeight: newHeight
    }, function() {
      parent.css({
        height: "",
        maxHeight: "",
        minHeight: ""
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I am currently setting up a jsfiddle with what I have but am definitely looking into your code as well. Maybe that .promise() is what I am looking for. I'm doing a similar thing right now but I guess that I have an error at the point where I set the `top`value of the new table.

Comment: Btw thanks for your examples. I have put your example into a jsfiddle too [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bKvxm). The problem I am facing is that I want to prepend the new table and that doesn't seem to be possible without hide() and slideDown() which seems to stutter a lot.

Comment: @ovm: You want the table to come down from the top rather than up from the bottom?

Comment: @ovm: I've shown how to do that. I think the various techniques demonstrated by the code should help you get where you want to get to. Best,